# remove unique_ptr from queue

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr

I'm trying to figure out how/if I can use `unique_ptr` in a `queue`.

```
// create queue
std::queue<std::unique_ptr<int>> q;

// add element
std::unique_ptr<int> p (new int{123});
q.push(std::move(p));

// try to grab the element
auto p2 = foo_queue.front();
q.pop();
```

I do understand why the code above doesn't work.  Since the `front` & `pop` are 2 separate steps, the element cannot be moved. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

You should say explicitly that you want to *move* the pointer *out of the queue*. Like this:

```
std::unique_ptr<int> p2 = std::move(q.front());
q.pop();
```

Comment: @iliacholy: loosely speaking, `q.front()` returns an *l-value*, so you cannot copy-initialize `p2` with it because `unique_ptr`s are not copyable. `std::move` converts it to an *r-value*, so now `p2` is being move-initialized instead, which is allowed by design.

Comment: I didn't think that `front` would be allowed to return it as an `l-value`.

Comment: @iliacholy: Why not? It returns a non-const reference to the element withing the queue.

Comment: Ah ok, that makes sense! For some reason I thought the `unique_ptr` was being returned by value.

Comment: Also important is that after the `move`, the top element in the `queue` is a `unique_ptr` equal to `nullptr`. The pop is needed to remove this "empty" `unique_ptr` from the `queue`.

Comment: why wouldn't pop() just return the top item as an rvalue, I wonder?

Comment: @Mordachai: exception safety requires it.

Comment: @rubenvb it is not required to be null, strictly speaking. After move-constructing from it, it's just an invalid object, not owning a resource. Of course that is most easily implemented by making it null

Comment: @Mordachai: efficiency. Sometimes you can just as well use the object in the queue through the reference returned by `front()` and then delete and forget about it. Also in C++03 you could not implement an efficient return by value for `pop()`.

Comment: @Mordachai Exception safety: it is to prevent losing the element from the queue in the case the copy construction involved in the return throws an exception.

Comment: All of which combine to make it a terrible interface for a smarter-pointer based stack or queue.  Interesting, but C++ constantly makes pointed-to vs. by-copy require very different semantics to make things work well, IMO.