# C++ multiple unique pointers from same raw pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, unique-ptr

Consider my code below. My understanding of unique pointers was that only one unique pointer can be used to reference one variable or object. In my code I have more than one unique_ptr accessing the same variable.

It's obviously not the correct way to use smart pointers i know, in that the pointer should have complete ownership from creation. But still, why is this valid and not having a compilation error? Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int val = 0;
    int* valPtr = &val;

    unique_ptr <int> uniquePtr1(valPtr);
    unique_ptr <int> uniquePtr2(valPtr);

    *uniquePtr1 = 10;
    *uniquePtr2 = 20;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `>>why is this valid` It is not and triggers assert in VS

Comment: @KillzoneKid: with the `/MTd` flag.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Yes, still crashes though.

Comment: @KillzoneKid: Yes, of course, just wanted to point out that this is not the compiler's default behaviour. Without the flag, you may or may not get a crash, even with the very same *.exe file executed a few times in a row.

Comment: Why is this question downvoted? It's a very valid concern if you are not experienced in C++.

Comment: I just checked whether clang-tidy would flag it. Nope.

Answer (score 10):

> But still, why is this valid

It is **not** valid! It's undefined behaviour, because the destructor of `std::unique_ptr` will free an object with automatic storage duration.

Practically, your program tries to destroy the `int` object three times. First through `uniquePtr2`, then through `uniquePtr1`, and then through `val` itself.

> and not having a compilation error?

Because such errors are not generally detectable at compile time:

```
unique_ptr <int> uniquePtr1(valPtr);
unique_ptr <int> uniquePtr2(function_with_runtime_input());
```

In this example, `function_with_runtime_input()` may perform a lot of complicated runtime operations which eventually return a pointer to the same object `valPtr` points to.

---

If you use `std::unique_ptr` correctly, then you will almost always use `std::make_unique`, which prevents such errors.

Answer (score 4):

Just an addition to Christian Hackl's excellent answer:

`std::unique_ptr` was introduced to ensure [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization) for pointers; this means, in opposite to raw pointers you don't have to take care about destruction yourself anymore. The whole management of the raw pointer is done by the smart pointer. Leaks caused by a forgotten `delete` can not happen anymore.

If a `std::unique_ptr` would only allow to be created by `std::make_unique`, it would be absolutely safe regarding allocation and deallocation, and of course that would be also detectable during compile time.

But that's not the case: `std::unique_ptr` is also constructible with a raw pointer. The reason is, that being able to be constructed with a hard pointer makes a `std::unique_ptr` much more useful. If this would not be possible, e.g. the pointer returned by Christian Hackl's `function_with_runtime_input()` would not be possible to integrate into a modern RAII environment, you would have to take care of destruction yourself.

Of course the downside with this is that errors like yours can happen: To forget destruction is not possible with `std::unique_ptr`, but erroneous multiple destructions are always possible (and impossible to track by the compiler, as C.H. already said), if you created it with a raw pointer constructor argument. Always be aware that `std::unique_ptr` logically takes "ownership" of the raw pointer - what means, that no one else may delete the pointer except the one `std::unique_ptr` itself.

As rules of thumb it can be said:

- Always create a `std::unique_ptr` with `std::make_unique` if possible.
- If it needs to be constructed with a raw pointer, never touch the raw pointer after creating the `std::unique_ptr` with it.
- Always be aware, that the `std::unique_ptr` takes ownership of the supplied raw pointer
- Only supply raw pointers to the heap. NEVER use raw pointers which point to local
  stack variables (because they will be unavoidably destroyed automatically,
  like `val`in your example).
- Create a `std::unique_ptr` only with raw pointers, which were created by `new`, if possible.
- If the `std::unique_ptr` needs to be constructed with a raw pointer, which was created by something else than `new`, add a custom deleter to the `std::unique_ptr`, which matches the hard pointer creator. An example are image pointers in the (C based) [FreeImage](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/) library, which always have to be destroyed by `FreeImage_Unload()`

Some examples to these rules:

```
// Safe
std::unique_ptr<int> p = std::make_unique<int>();

// Safe, but not advisable. No accessible raw pointer exists, but should use make_unique. 
std::unique_ptr<int> p(new int());

// Handle with care. No accessible raw pointer exists, but it has to be sure
// that function_with_runtime_input() allocates the raw pointer with 'new'
std::unique_ptr<int> p( function_with_runtime_input() );

// Safe. No accessible raw pointer exists,
// the raw pointer is created by a library, and has a custom
// deleter to match the library's requirements
struct FreeImageDeleter {
    void operator() (FIBITMAP* _moribund) { FreeImage_Unload(_moribund); }
};
std::unique_ptr<FIBITMAP,FreeImageDeleter> p( FreeImage_Load(...) );

// Dangerous. Your class method gets a raw pointer
// as a parameter. It can not control what happens
// with this raw pointer after the call to MyClass::setMySomething()
// - if the caller deletes it, your'e lost.
void MyClass::setMySomething( MySomething* something ) {
   // m_mySomethingP is a member std::unique_ptr<Something>
   m_mySomethingP = std::move( std::unique_ptr<Something>( something ));
}

// Dangerous. A raw pointer variable exists, which might be erroneously
// deleted multiple times or assigned to a std::unique_ptr multiple times.
// Don't touch iPtr after these lines!
int* iPtr = new int();
std::unique_ptr<int> p(iPtr);

// Wrong (Undefined behaviour) and a direct consequence of the dangerous declaration above.
// A raw pointer is assigned to a std::unique_ptr<int> twice, which means
// that it will be attempted to delete it twice.
// This couldn't have happened if iPtr wouldn't have existed in the first
// place, like shown in the 'safe' examples.
int* iPtr = new int();
std::unique_ptr<int> p(iPtr);
std::unique_ptr<int> p2(iPtr);


// Wrong. (Undefined behaviour)
// An unique pointer gets assigned a raw pointer to a stack variable.
// Erroneous double destruction is the consequence
int val;
int* valPtr = &val;
std::unique_ptr<int> p(valPtr);
```

Answer (score 0):

This example of code is a bit artificial. `unique_ptr` is not usually initialized this way in real world code. Use [`std::make_unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) or initialize `unique_ptr` without storing raw pointer in a variable:

```
unique_ptr <int> uniquePtr2(new int);
```