# std::move const reference of unqiue_ptr

Tags: c++, priority-queue, unique-ptr

Moving a const reference to a unique_ptr fails to compile. Problem comes about when I try to do `top()` on a `priority_queue` and then `pop()` the top. I can't get the item before the `pop()`!

```
const std::unique_ptr<int>& refToPtr = pqueue.back();
std::unique_ptr<int> ptr = std::move(refToPtr); // fails to compile
```

Here is a full example.

```
#include <memory>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::unique_ptr<int> initial = std::make_unique<int>(4);
    std::priority_queue<std::unique_ptr<int>> queue;
    queue.push(std::move(initial));
    const std::unique_ptr<int>& refToPtr = queue.top();
    std::unique_ptr<int> ptr = std::move(refToPtr); // won't compile???
    queue.pop();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No question has been asked, but this is correct behavior.  If a `unique_ptr` is const, you can not move it.  The purpose of `const` is to prevent change.

Comment: Why are you using a reference to `const`?  A `const` thing can't be moved as moving involves modifying the object.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes, thank you for asking. I tried to state my reason in the question. I have a `priority_queue<unique_ptr<T>>`. `std::priority_queue.top()` returns a const reference. I need to get that value before popping.

Comment: Based on the details provided in the comments, this question is a duplicate.

Comment: Potential duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16661038

Comment: The best solution is probably to implement your own priority queue with a mutable `top`, or with a returning `pop`. You can implement this without too much trouble by storing elements in list and using a priority_queue of iterators to elements of that list.