# How to convert from base class to derived class?

Tags: c++, class, data-binding, c++11, polymorphism

I want to make a multi-threaded model in which the server main loop will not be stalled by pending database transactions. So I made a few simple classes, this is a very simplified version:

```
enum Type
{
    QueryType_FindUser      = 1 << 0,
    QueryType_RegisterUser  = 1 << 1,
    QueryType_UpdateUser    = 1 << 2,
    //lots lots and lots of more types
};

class Base
{       
public:
    Type type;
};
class User: public Base
{   
public:
    std::string username;
    User(std::string username)
        :username(username)
    {type = QueryType_FindUser;}        
};
```

Now when I transfer the data as a `Base`, I want to convert it back to `User` class again:

```
concurrency::concurrent_queue<QueryInformation::Base> BackgroundQueryQueue;
void BackgroundQueryWorker::Worker()
{
    while(ServerRunning)
    {
        QueryInformation::Base Temp;
        if(BackgroundQueryQueue.try_pop(Temp))
        {
            switch(Temp.type)
            {
                case QueryInformation::Type::QueryType_FindUser:
                {
                    QueryInformation::User ToFind(static_cast<QueryInformation::User>(Temp));//error here
                    //do sql query with user information
                    break;
                }
                //etc
            }
        }
        boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(SleepTime));
    }
}
```

Where I marked the `//errorhere` line it says that there is no user-defined conversion from `Base` to `User`, what should I do? How can I define this conversion?

I'm new to polymorphism so an additional explaination why this doesn't compile would be also great :)
From what I understood about polymorphism it should be doable to convert freely between base<->derived..

Comment: hm, I cant remember when I type-casted the last time without using pointers ( eg `static_cast<QueryInformation::User*>(&Temp)` ) . Sadly I could not find the corresponding manual pages and its friday ( brain empty )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only use polymorphism by using *pointers* or *references*, not direct values.

hence, you should use:

```
QueryInformation::User * user = static_cast<QueryInformation::User *>(&Temp);
```

and modify your code accordingly to use the pointer instead of the direct value.

Furthermore, the way you allocated `Temp`, it is indeed of class `Base`, not of class `User`, hence its "type" will not be `QueryType_FindUser`, and then `static_cast` will not be perform (you will not enter the `case` value).

The normal use of polymorphism with `static_cast` should look like this:

```
QueryInformation::Base * temp = new QueryInformation::User; 
// or obtain by some other methods, so that you don't know the exact
// type, but anyway you *must* use a pointer (or reference).

switch(temp->type)
{
case QueryInformation::Type::QueryType_FindUser:
    {
        QueryInformation::User * user = static_cast<QueryInformation::User*>(temp);
    }
}
```

In your case, this means instead of having:

```
concurrency::concurrent_queue<QueryInformation::Base> BackgroundQueryQueue;
```

you should have (note the pointer):

```
concurrency::concurrent_queue<QueryInformation::Base *> BackgroundQueryQueue;
```

And as Mats suggested, it is probably even better to call a virtual method of `Base` that will do the dispatch automatically, instead of creating yourself a `switch` and making manually a `static_cast`.

Comment: Technically, this won't work, since the stored object has already been sliced and the "extra" bits in `User` have gone missing.

Comment: yes, I believe it would be best to mark Base class abstract ( enforcing pointers and everything else pretty much to be in the correct design )

Comment: Nitpicking: polymorphism also works with references, not only pointers.

Comment: @MatsPetersson, I edited my answer to reflect this. The code was *semantically* wrong, but technically correct. Just the static_cast would never occur in the first place since the Base was *not* of type User.

Comment: @syam: yes, I assumed this was obvious since references are pointers underneath (and I actually used references in my code..) but better make it clear.

Comment: when I `delete user` when done (in you second example) will the memory be totally freed by that one object? What should I use for auto memory management? auto_ptr? weak_ptr? lazy_ptr? shared_ptr? Unique_ptr? There are too many :/

Comment: @Gizmo: I am not an expert in smart pointers, but to the best of my knowledge, I would recommend you use `unique_ptr`: `concurrent_queue< std::unique_ptr<Base> >`. This means the ownership of your pointers is only retained by the queue, and the memory will be released as soon as the queue is destroyed. If you pop the element from the list, then you should move the ownership to the caller of "pop", like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14127487/remove-unique-ptr-from-queue), then perform the static cast like this: `User * user = static_cast<User*>(q2.get());`.

Comment: @Gizmo Oh, and in any ways, you *must* use a [virtual destructor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/461203/when-to-use-virtual-destructors) for Base. Hence, when `delete base` is called (either by yourself or by the smart pointer), the appropriate destructor will be called. (for instance, ~User)

Comment: unresolved symbol public: virtual __thiscall ResultInformation::Base::~Base(void) when I declare `virtual ~Base();` :(

Comment: ah nvm `virtual ~Base(){}` is Ok.

Comment: @Gizmo yep, if you declare a non-default desctructor, you *must* also provide the implementation. [*Even in the case when you declare it pure virtual*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/630950/pure-virtual-destructor-in-c) (this can be surprising at first).

Answer (score 1):

To me, this seems all a bit wrong.

First, your data structure `concurrent_queue<QueryInformation::Base>` is storing the `Base` object, which means that any additional information in the actual object (e.g. `User`) will be lost due to slicing. You need to use a (smart) pointer to store the address of a `Base` object - which will then be able to hold any size object.

Second, surely, this should use virtual functions to achieve the required tasks. If you store what type object it is and then call `dynamic_cast` to convert the object, it's "wrong". Sure, there are some rare circumstance when this is the right thing to do, but most of the time, `dynamic_cast` (or `static_cast`) to convert between one object and another is a "bad smell", and as you probably know, bad smells should be avoided.

Comment: +1 I added this recommendation to my own answer since this is the one the OP has accepted (didn't use a smart pointer for clarity).