# Does the C++ queue destroy the object after pop?

Tags: c++

Some simple code show first:

Type A:

```
//create a queue

queue<my_class*> temp;
//add some element some pointers;

temp.push(A);
temp.push(B);
...

//then i want to delete the first element ;

temp.pop();
```

**Question 1:** When call temp.pop() it will release all the object memory
A used? 
If not , what i should do ?

Type B:

```
//create a queue

queue<my_class> temp;
//add some element some pointers;

temp.push(A);
temp.push(B);
...

//then i want to delete the first element ;

temp.pop();
```

**Question 2:** What's difference with the Type A and Type B;

Answer (score 3):

**Q2:** `pop` for *Type A* and *Type B* does the same thing, the `pop` destructs the type that is defined in the template argument (for *Type A* its a pointer to `my_class` for *Type B* it is `my_class`). So *Type A* destructs a pointer *Type B* destructs an instance of `my_class`.

**Q1:** Yes as `A` is just a pointer. But it does not destruct the object `A` is pointing to. So the instance of `my_class` is not released.

Answer (score 2):

`pop()` indeed destroys the first element.

Note however that in the first case the `std::queue` is **of naked pointers** and destroying a naked pointer doesn't do anything to the pointed-to object.

In the second case the `std::queue` contains **object copies** so when calling `pop()` the first copy will be destroyed and removed.

In the first case unless someone else knows the address of the object pointed to by the destroyed pointer and calls `delete` on that address, the object will be "leaked" (i.e. just forgotten about): its destructor will never be called and the memory it is using will never be reclaimed and reused for something else.

To destroy the pointed-to object in the first case the normal procedure is

```
delete queue.front();
queue.pop();
```

If instead of "naked" pointer you use "smart" pointers then the "leak" problem will go away in most cases<sup>(*)</sup>. Note that it doesn't mean the destructor of the pointed-to object will be called in `pop()`, but that it will called at the appropriate time when no one else knows the address of the pointed-to object (if everything is done correctly when manipulating the smart pointers).

---

<sup>(*)</sup> If your data model is complex and you have `std::shared_ptr` networks of objects pointing to each other then there is a risk of creating "reference loops". In this case `std::shared_ptr` even if used correctly is not enough to prevent leaking of loops (e.g. leaking a cople of objects `A` and `B` where each one has a `std::shared_ptr` to the other) and a true garbage collector is needed. Unfortunately C++ doesn't provide this kind of machinery in the standard library.

Comment: Instead of manually deleting, one should prefer smart pointers of course, like `std::queue<std::unique_ptr<my_class>>`.

Comment: @chtz Can you give me a demo code for how to use the std::queue<std::unique_ptr<my_class>>

Comment: @chtz: I've added a note on smart pointers... they're good but it's important to remember they're not a silver bullet. The only option in C++ is to think hard to ownership (or implement/use a garbage collector).

Comment: @6502 True, storing by value should always be the first option. Only if that is too expensive (or there is another constraint), storing (smart) pointers should be considered. At OP: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14127487/remove-unique-ptr-from-queue